# display AM/PM format in time_select tag in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using

```
<%= f.time_select :time_from ,  :minute_step => 15 %>
```

to display time select option with a step of 15 mins.

Its showing 24hours clock. I want to show 12hour clock in display section (user view) and 24hour clock in value section (for back ground processing.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 12 hour plugin for this.

http://code.google.com/p/rails-twelve-hour-time-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

The plug-in is pretty old.  For Rails 3, see https://gist.github.com/1340125.  Rails 3.1 has a built-in option.

Comment: but it was working perfectly with rails 3.0.1, but still thnks for the tip.

Comment: Fair enough.  I hadn't tried it, but read elsewhere that it was causing problems.

Comment: no i used it in three project at that time. 3.0.1, 3.0.2 * 2 and it was working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add am and pm to your time by putting this

```
<%= f.time_select :time,  {ampm: true},placeholder: "Pickup time"%>
```